# Data in database is not visible despite migrations

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, code-first

I have a project that I developed with Asp.Net MVC5. I created the database of the project with the CodeFirst approach. When I finished I uploaded my project to github.

However, after downloading the project from github and saying "enable -migrations" and "update-database", the data in my tables is not coming.

If my internship teacher wants to test this project on his computer, he will create the database, but he will have problems because there is no data in the tables. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I would guess that your project dose not contain the data. Very difficult for us to know when we have no access to your code, project, or respository.

Comment: If you are talking about data within the tables, have you configure any type of seeding for your application?

Comment: Databases normally have to functionalities named `dump` and `restore`. For example, on MySql you can backup a database into a file from the command-line using `mysqldump`. What this is going to do is to create a text file full of SQL queries. These queries will create the tables and then insert all the data into them. So, your project should be able to execute this file if it detects that the database isn't existent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use code first migrations to seed the database. See link for more information on it. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3) This should make your database start with data.